# Decode berkeley db strings

Tags: python, hex, ascii, decode, berkeley-db

Having trouble decoding data from berkeley db. 
I've dumped data with `db4.8_dump` or `db4.8_dump -p` and decoding using `python.decode()`

So, here's what the data looks like after db4.8_dump in hex coding

```
036b65794104053ca761cf8062cfff09a2ec355a2694da4eed0677b510cf0c43a0d8486694e9966f2133302c5aa51664e9003b04cfa3847ce20de92040844b9b05aa15b5ab58
```

and same data with `-p` switch `db4.8_dump -p`:

```
\03keyA\04\05<\a7a\cf\80b\cf\ff\09\a2\ec5Z&\94\daN\ed\06w\b5\10\cf\0cC\a0\d8Hf\94\e9\96o!30,Z\a5\16d\e9\00;\04\cf\a3\84|\e2\0d\e9 @\84K\9b\05\aa\15\b5\abX
```

I can decode it like his, but still unreadable :

```py
mbstr = b'036b65794104053ca761cf8062cfff09a2ec355a2694da4eed0677b510cf0c43a0d8486694e9966f2133302c5aa51664e9003b04cfa3847ce20de92040844b9b05aa15b5ab58'

mbstr.decode('hex')
'\x03keyA\x04\x05<\xa7a\xcf\x80b\xcf\xff\t\xa2\xec5Z&\x94\xdaN\xed\x06w\xb5\x10\xcf\x0cC\xa0\xd8Hf\x94\xe9\x96o!30,Z\xa5\x16d\xe9\x00;\x04\xcf\xa3\x84|\xe2\r\xe9 @\x84K\x9b\x05\xaa\x15\xb5\xabX'
```

Per documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/programmer_reference/dumpload_format.html

> If the backslash character precedes any other character, the next two characters must be interpreted as hexadecimal specification of a single character; for example, \0a is a newline character in the ASCII character set.
>   but this doesn't work for me. i.e.

```py
>>> mbstr.decode('hex')
'\x03keyA\x04\x05<\xa7a\xcf\x80b\xcf\xff\t\xa2\xec5Z&\x94\xdaN\xed\x06w\xb5\x10\xcf\x0cC\xa0\xd8Hf\x94\xe9\x96o!30,Z\xa5\x16d\xe9\x00;\x04\xcf\xa3\x84|\xe2\r\xe9 @\x84K\x9b\x05\xaa\x15\xb5\xabX'
>>> mbstr.decode('hex').decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I convert data into readable string format? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Berkeley DB keys and data are frequently not strings.  Actually, I can't recall a time when I've ever used strings for the keys.  Data, sure.  Sometimes.  But the key comparison function is so performance critical, it nearly always makes sense to represent keys in binary, like it would sit in a packed C struct.

To make sense of the data stored in Berkeley DB, you need the source code for the application that populated it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, makes more sense now. The data is from my old wallet.dat , I've asked question to developers recently and haven't got full answer or just unable to figure it out. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/881#issuecomment-561364689
Source code of the application is here - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/wallet/walletdb.cpp
Thanks